# Using shared_ptr with multi inheritance class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, smart-pointers

I have an class which inherit two interfaces:

```
class Multi : public IFoo, public IBar {
public:
  virtual ~Multi();

  // Foo part
  virtual void fooMethod();
  // ...

  // Bar part
  virtual void barMethod();
  // ...
};
```

Unfortunately this class cannot be decomposed in two separate classes for each interface. In fact in class implementation those entities (Foo and Bar) are tightly coupled, but in future they could become separate.

Another one class wants to use Multi class, having a pointer to IFoo and IBar:

```
class ClientClass {
    public:
       ClientClass(); // constructor
       // smth
    private:
       std::shared_ptr<IFoo> foo_;
       std::shared_ptr<IBar> bar_;
};
```

In constructor I do something like:

```
ClientClass::ClientClass(){
    auto pMulti = new Multi;
    foo_ = std::shared_ptr<IFoo>(pMulti);
    bar_= std::shared_ptr<IBar>(pMulti);  
}
```

But each of those shared pointers has separate reference counter, and it leads to deleting already deleted pointer on class destruction, am I right?

1. How should I treat it?
2. What is best practics for such case?

Comment: It looks like you should make IFoo and IBar separate right now. :)

Comment: @Jerry I couldn't make them separate because they have common initialization, common releasing etc, and I can't change this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ClientClass::ClientClass()
{
    auto pMulti = std::make_shared<Multi>();
    foo_ = pMulti;
    bar_ = pMulti;  
}
```

would ensure that they have the same reference counter. You can see it for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base1{};
class Base2{};
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {};

int main()
{
    auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base1> base1 = derived;
    std::shared_ptr<Base2> base2 = derived;

    std::cout << "base1 usecount = " << base1.use_count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "base2 usecount = " << base2.use_count() << '\n';
    std::cout << "derived usecount = " << derived.use_count() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
base1 usecount = 3
base2 usecount = 3
derived usecount = 3
```

Comment: Are you sure that shared_ptr's assign operator allows use different template type for argument? shared_ptr<IFoo> = shared_ptr<Multi> ?

Comment: @vard Yes, as long as the type on the right side is inherited from the one on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do with those pointers, but an alternative solution may be to store a `std::unique_ptr<multi> multi_;` and have a couple of interface functions that static cast it to plain pointers or to references:

```
IFoo& ClientClass::get_ifoo() {
  return *(static_cast<IFoo*>(multi_.get())); 
}

IBar& ClientClass::get_ibar() {
  return *(static_cast<IBar*>(multi_.get())); 
}
```

As long as you don't pass those out from the class, and don't call `delete[]` on them it should be quite safe.

Comment: Do you even need the casts here? (i.e. there is no point for these functions.)

Comment: @juanchopanza At a deeper look I see, but so should be the idea of having shared pointers, right?